# Flex size adapt to child div

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS to create my css and trying to figure out how to utilize the flexbox classes to make the parent div be the size of width of my child divs so I can center the image and title without it centering to the center of the page. Would I need to set up an empty div that utilizes the space to the right of this div or a flexbox style that takes this action appropriately?

**Code:**

```
<div className="flex flex-col p-5">
  <a
    onClick={() => {
      mediaPlayerState(true);
      setNum(randomYTVideoGenerator(1, 5));
      console.log(num);
    }}
  >
    <Image
      className="pb-1 items-center"
      src="/windows-media-player.png"
      width={50}
      height={50}
    ></Image>
    <div className="text-white font-semibold">Media Player</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

[image: div]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider either:

- Applying `width: max-content` to the `<div>` via the `w-max` class.
- Applying `display: inline-flex` instead of `display: flex` to the `<div>` via the `inline-flex` class.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<body class="bg-slate-950">
  <div class="flex flex-col p-5 w-max">
    <a>
      <img
        class="pb-1 items-center"
        src="https://picsum.photos/50/50"
        width={50}
        height={50}
      />
      <div class="text-white font-semibold">Media Player</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="inline-flex flex-col p-5">
    <a>
      <img
        class="pb-1 items-center"
        src="https://picsum.photos/50/50"
        width={50}
        height={50}
      />
      <div class="text-white font-semibold">Media Player</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```